# img scale(zoom in effect) doesn't work

Tags: css

I have a question.

I want to zoom in img on hover but it doesn't work.

```
<div>
<img src="https://www.apple.com/v/iphone/home/x/images/home/business_addit_large.jpg">
</div>

<style>
div {width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow:hidden}
img {display: block; margin:auto;width: 500px; height: 300px;}
img:hover {transform: scale(1,1);}
</style>
```

Here is code.

Comment: typo `scale(1,1)` => `scale(1.1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow:hidden}
img {display: block; margin:auto;width: 500px; height: 300px; transition: transform 1s;}
img:hover {transform: scale(1.1);}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://www.apple.com/v/iphone/home/x/images/home/business_addit_large.jpg">
</div>
```

It is just a typo `scale(1,1)` => `scale(1.1)`

In addition, if you want to add smooth effect, you should add `transition` like that.

Answer (score 0):

Typo error. It is `transform: scale(1.1)`. I have added `transition: 0.5s transform linear` to image to smoothen the effect.

```css
div {width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow:hidden}
img {display: block; margin:auto;width: 500px; height: 300px; transition:0.5s transform linear; }
img:hover {transform: scale(1.1);}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://www.apple.com/v/iphone/home/x/images/home/business_addit_large.jpg">
</div>
```